# Reading SMART Data - What does it mean?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, smart, raspbian

I have this drive attached to a raspi that, all of the sudden, became extremely slow. On another site, someone recommended to run `smartctl -a /dev/sdc` but I don't know what I'm looking at and how to fix it (if possible at all)

**$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc**

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [armv7l-linux-4.14.62-v7+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST2000DM001-1E6164
Serial Number:    W1E66VJ8
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 03d263f01
Firmware Version: SC48
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Sep 12 23:34:28 2018 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

Read SMART Data failed: Connection timed out

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: Connection timed out
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 620 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 620 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:57.935  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:49.641  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:49.021  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:48.238  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:48.084  READ DMA EXT

Error 619 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:57.935  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:49.641  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:49.021  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:48.238  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:48.084  READ DMA EXT

Error 618 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:49.641  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:49.021  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:48.238  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:48.084  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:48.083  READ DMA EXT

Error 617 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:49.641  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:49.021  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:48.238  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:48.084  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:28:48.083  READ DMA EXT

Error 616 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:27:28.523  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:27:25.103  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:27:25.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:27:25.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:27:25.101  READ DMA EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported

pi@soul:/media/d $ sudo smartctl -t /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [armv7l-linux-4.14.62-v7+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=======> INVALID ARGUMENT TO -t: /dev/sdc
=======> VALID ARGUMENTS ARE: offline, short, long, conveyance, force, vendor,N, select,M-N, pending,N, afterselect,[on|off] <=======

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary
```

**sudo smartctl -x /dev/sdc**

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [armv7l-linux-4.14.62-v7+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST2000DM001-1E6164
Serial Number:    W1E66VJ8
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 03d263f01
Firmware Version: SC48
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Sep 12 23:39:37 2018 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM level is:     128 (minimum power consumption without standby)
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
ATA Security is:  Disabled, NOT FROZEN [SEC1]
Wt Cache Reorder: Unavailable

Read SMART Data failed: Connection timed out

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status command failed: Connection timed out
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: UNKNOWN!
SMART Status, Attributes and Thresholds cannot be read.

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      5  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x21       GPL     R/O      1  Write stream error log
0x22       GPL     R/O      1  Read stream error log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS      20  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL     VS    4496  Device vendor specific log
0xa8       GPL,SL  VS     129  Device vendor specific log
0xa9       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xab       GPL     VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xb0       GPL     VS    5176  Device vendor specific log
0xbd       GPL     VS     512  Device vendor specific log
0xbe-0xbf  GPL     VS   65535  Device vendor specific log
0xc0       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc1       GPL,SL  VS      10  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (5 sectors)
Device Error Count: 620 (device log contains only the most recent 20 errors)
        CR     = Command Register
        FEATR  = Features Register
        COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
        LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
        LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
        LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
        LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
        DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
        DC     = Device Control Register
        ER     = Error register
        ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 620 [19] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 3c 6c 41 40 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3c6c4140 = 1013727552

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 41 40 40 00     00:28:57.935  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 41 40 40 00     00:28:49.641  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 41 38 40 00     00:28:49.021  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 40 68 40 00     00:28:48.238  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 40 60 40 00     00:28:48.084  READ DMA EXT

Error 619 [18] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 3c 6c 41 40 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3c6c4140 = 1013727552

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 41 40 40 00     00:28:57.935  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 41 40 40 00     00:28:49.641  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 41 38 40 00     00:28:49.021  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 40 68 40 00     00:28:48.238  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 40 60 40 00     00:28:48.084  READ DMA EXT

Error 618 [17] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 3c 6c 41 40 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3c6c4140 = 1013727552

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 41 40 40 00     00:28:49.641  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 41 38 40 00     00:28:49.021  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 40 68 40 00     00:28:48.238  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 40 60 40 00     00:28:48.084  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 40 58 40 00     00:28:48.083  READ DMA EXT

Error 617 [16] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 3c 6c 41 40 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3c6c4140 = 1013727552

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 41 40 40 00     00:28:49.641  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 41 38 40 00     00:28:49.021  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 40 68 40 00     00:28:48.238  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 40 60 40 00     00:28:48.084  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 6c 40 58 40 00     00:28:48.083  READ DMA EXT

Error 616 [15] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 3c 69 fa 70 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3c69fa70 = 1013578352

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 70 40 00     00:27:28.523  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 70 40 00     00:27:25.103  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 68 40 00     00:27:25.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 60 40 00     00:27:25.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 58 40 00     00:27:25.101  READ DMA EXT

Error 615 [14] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 3c 69 fa 70 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3c69fa70 = 1013578352

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 70 40 00     00:27:28.523  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 70 40 00     00:27:25.103  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 68 40 00     00:27:25.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 60 40 00     00:27:25.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 58 40 00     00:27:25.101  READ DMA EXT

Error 614 [13] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 3c 69 fa 70 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3c69fa70 = 1013578352

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 70 40 00     00:27:25.103  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 68 40 00     00:27:25.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 60 40 00     00:27:25.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 58 40 00     00:27:25.101  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 50 40 00     00:27:25.100  READ DMA EXT

Error 613 [12] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 37859 hours (1577 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 00 00 00 3c 69 fa 70 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x3c69fa70 = 1013578352

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 70 40 00     00:27:25.103  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 68 40 00     00:27:25.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 60 40 00     00:27:25.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 58 40 00     00:27:25.101  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 3c 69 fa 50 40 00     00:27:25.100  READ DMA EXT

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       522 (0x020a)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    45 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     40/47 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     18/58 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0

SCT Data Table command not supported

SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported

Device Statistics (GP/SMART Log 0x04) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x000a  2          911  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
```

Answer (score 2):

Seeing a lot of "*Read SMART Data failed: Connection timed out*" messages, that might be unusual. Doesn't look like the `-A, --attributes` are getting read, for some reason.

Anyway, instead of digging through all the numbers yourself, you could try a GUI like [`gsmartctrl`](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/) a "graphical user interface for smartctl." It's got some [features](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/About) like:

- ***automatically reports and highlights any anomalies;***
- performs SMART self-tests;
- displays drive identity information, capabilities, attributes, device statistics, etc...;
- can read in smartctl output from a saved file, interpreting it as a read-only virtual device;
- has extensive help information.

[image: Drive information window - A failing drive, attribute list]

---

smartctl's man page has some info about the SMART attributes, it looks like the raw values may not always correspond directly to the attribute in an obvious way, here's an excerpt:

```
          Each  Attribute  has  a  "Raw"  value,  printed  under  the  heading
          "RAW_VALUE",  and  a  "Normalized"  value  printed under the heading
          "VALUE".  [Note: smartctl prints these values in base-10.]   In  the
          example  just  given,  the "Raw Value" for Attribute 12 would be the
          actual number of times that the  disk  has  been  power-cycled,  for
          example  365 if the disk has been turned on once per day for exactly
          one year.  Each vendor uses their  own  algorithm  to  convert  this
          "Raw"  value  to  a  "Normalized"  value in the range from 1 to 254.
          Please keep  in  mind  that  smartctl  only  reports  the  different
          Attribute types, values, and thresholds as read from the device.  It
          does not carry out the conversion  between  "Raw"  and  "Normalized"
          values: this is done by the disk´s firmware.

          The  conversion  from Raw value to a quantity with physical units is
          not specified by the SMART  standard.  In  most  cases,  the  values
          printed  by  smartctl  are  sensible.   For  example the temperature
          Attribute generally has its raw value equal to  the  temperature  in
          Celsius.   However  in  some  cases vendors use unusual conventions.
          For example the Hitachi disk on my laptop reports its power-on hours
          in  minutes,  not  hours.  Some  IBM  disks track three temperatures
          rather than one, in their raw values.  And so on.
```

...

```
          Please note: the fact
          that an Attribute is of type 'Pre-fail' does not mean that your disk
          is about to fail!  It only has this meaning if the Attribute´s  cur‐
          rent Normalized value is less than or equal to the threshold value.
```

...

```
          If the Attribute´s current Normalized value is less than or equal to
          the threshold value, then  the  "WHEN_FAILED"  column  will  display
          "FAILING_NOW".  If not, but the worst recorded value is less than or
          equal  to  the  threshold  value,  then  this  column  will  display
          "In_the_past".   If the "WHEN_FAILED" column has no entry (indicated
          by a dash: ´-´) then this Attribute is OK now (not failing) and  has
          also never failed in the past.
```

...

```
          So to summarize: the Raw Attribute values are the  ones  that  might
          have  a real physical interpretation, such as "Temperature Celsius",
          "Hours", or "Start-Stop Cycles".  Each manufacturer converts  these,
          using  their detailed knowledge of the disk´s operations and failure
          modes, to Normalized Attribute values in the range 1-254.  The  cur‐
          rent  and worst (lowest measured) of these Normalized Attribute val‐
          ues are stored on the disk, along with a Threshold  value  that  the
          manufacturer  has determined will indicate that the disk is going to
          fail, or that it  has  exceeded  its  design  age  or  aging  limit.
          smartctl does not calculate any of the Attribute values, thresholds,
          or types, it merely reports them from the SMART data on the device.
```

Comment: I have the Raspbian without desktop, so I will try to get the tool on the Mac and connect the HD to it